# Problems with separator-encoding

Tags: regex, perl, encoding, cgi, ascii

If I run this script as it is, it works.
But why does this not work with `cgi`?
When I use `_\01_` instead of `_\00_` it works with `cgi` too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;


###    script_1.cgi    #########################################

my @array = ( '1524', '2.18 MB', '09/23/03', '_cool_name_', 'type' );
my $row = join "_\00_", @array;
say $row;
# submit $row to script_2.cgi


###    script_2.cgi    #########################################
# ...
# my $row = $cgi->param('row');
# my $name;

if ( $row =~ /_\00_([^\00]+)_\00_type\z/ ) {
#   $name = $1;
    say "Name: <$1>";
} else {
    die "<$row> $!";
}

# Software error:
# <1524_�_2.18 MB_�_09/23/03_�__cool_name__�_type>  at script_2.cgi line of "die "<$row> $!";"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me, says `_cool_name_`. You're probably running afoul of [CGI.pm using `\0` already for itself](http://p3rl.org/CGI#FETCHING_THE_PARAMETER_LIST_AS_A_HASH%3a), but since you did not post your complete code, no one can say for sure.

I'll use the opportunity to unask the question. The lessons you should learn are:

1. Avoid rolling your own serialisation scheme. As a beginner, you have made the typical mistake of not encoding the separator if it occurs in the data (c.f. double backslash in string expressions and double percent in sprintf expressions). The array could have been passed intact unjoined via e.g. [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON).
2. Instead of two scripts, these should be two subroutines in the same program. This way, you are able to pass data structures without the need to serialise.

Comment: It worked with JSON. But I did not yet understand the `you have made the typical mistake of not encoding the separator if it occurs in the data (c.f. double backslash in string expressions and double percent in sprintf expressions)`-part.

Comment: Think about special characters in strings which are denoted with a backslash. What do you do when you need to express the backslash itself? For a more complex example, study RLE in PCX. Then apply your knowledge to the situation what happens to your @array if any element already contains `\0`.